# Using jQuery's filter() function to extract an array with different criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a basic dataset stored in javascript that I want to filter based on user checked checkboxes. I know I can use jQuery's filter() function to filter the result set on multiple criteria, however the issue I'm running into is that the criteria would change depending on user input.

```
var myArray = [["Adelaide", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Ada", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Amanda", 1, "yes", "female"],
           ["Wolf", 3, "no", "male"],
           ["Rhonda", 1, "no", "female"]];
```

HTML:

```
<input id="rate-3" name="rating" type="checkbox" value="rate-3" />3 Stars<br />
<input id="rate-2" name="rating" type="checkbox" value="rate-2" />2 Stars<br />
<input id="rate-1" name="rating" type="checkbox" value="rate-1" />1 Star<br />
<a href="#" id="submitform">Submit Filters</a>
```

How would I pass multiple criteria to the .filter(function)? 
As an example, someone might select rate-1 and rate-3 checkboxes which is what I currently hard coded the function to look for, however I want it to be flexible depending on the user submitted input.

I guess I could just write a number of if/else statements but is there a more elegant way of doing this?

JQuery:

```
$("#submitform").click(function() {
    var userSelectedFilters = new Object();

    userSelectedFilters.rate3 = $("#rate-3").is(':checked');
    userSelectedFilters.rate2 = $("#rate-2").is(':checked');
    userSelectedFilters.rate1 = $("#rate-1").is(':checked');

    var filteredArray = myArray.filter(
    function(el) {
       // currently hardcoded
       return ((el[1] == 1) || (el[1] == 3));
     }
    );

});
```

Comment: `filter()` lets you pass a function in, instead of a selector. http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: right, well technically I am using it as a function but it's very basic at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build an array and check if that number is contained in the array: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSUug/1/)

```
$("#submitform").click(function() {
    var userSelectedFilters = [];

    $("#rate-3").is(':checked') && userSelectedFilters.push(3);
    $("#rate-2").is(':checked') && userSelectedFilters.push(2);
    $("#rate-1").is(':checked') && userSelectedFilters.push(1);

    var filteredArray = myArray.filter(
    function(el) {
       // currently hardcoded
        return userSelectedFilters.indexOf(el[1]) !== -1;
     }
    );
});
```

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) isn't universal though, but there is a shim:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this === void 0 || this === null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 0) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n !== n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n !== 0 && n !== window.Infinity && n !== -window.Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't worry about compatibility - it's going to be run on Firefox 3+ so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

you might to review your html and use name="rating[]" for each box, it will spare you a lot of headhache.

As it is, in your submit function:

```
$('input:checked').each( function () {
   userSelectedFilters[this.id] = this.id;
});
```

but again, the full stackofcode can be avoided, just do a little research on stackoverflow (or google). anyway: here is your code:

```
var myArray = [["Adelaide", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Ada", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Amanda", 1, "yes", "female"],
           ["Wolf", 3, "no", "male"],
           ["Rhonda", 1, "no", "female"]];

$("#submitform").click(function() {

    var choices = [];

    $('input:checked').each( function () {
       choices.push(this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1)); 

    });


    var filteredArray = myArray.filter(
    function(el) {

       for (i in choices) {
            if ( choices[i] == el[1] ) {
                return true;
            }
       }
       return false
     }
    );

    console.log (filteredArray );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var myArray = [["Adelaide", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Ada", 2, "yes", "female"],
           ["Amanda", 1, "yes", "female"],
           ["Wolf", 3, "no", "male"],
           ["Rhonda", 1, "no", "female"]];

$("#submitform").click(function() {

    var userSelectedFilters = [];
    $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
         userSelectedFilters.push(this.value)
    });



    var filteredArray = myArray.filter(
    function(el) {
       // currently hardcoded
        for (i =0, lungh = userSelectedFilters.length ; i< lungh; i++){
            console.log(userSelectedFilters[i]);
            if (el[1] == userSelectedFilters[i]){
               return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
     }
    );


});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pWJwt/